# Data augmentation for recommendation systems

Tags: recommender-system, autoencoder, overfitting, data-augmentation, noisification

I have a user-item matrix that I use to train a denoising autoencoder to predict the top-k items to recommend to the different users.

The idea is to corrupt the matrix by erasing a percentage `p` of the items that each users bought and train the autoencoder to reconstruct the uncorrupted matrix.

Following the implementation of [this paper](https://github.com/yjhamb/acda), I am currently erasing `20%` of the bought items.

I was wondering if it is legit to augment the dataset by first erasing the `p=20%` to create the "noised" matrix and, successively, use for instance `p=40%` and concatenate the two noised matrices and trin the autoencoder to reconstruct a stack of two uncorrupted matrices.

Is it reasonable or is it just an invitation for overfitting?